# Turning a two dimensional list into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, readfile

Ok, so I have read in a text file from a .txt file that came in the format as such:

```
home school 5
home office 10
home store 7
school store 8
office school 4
END OF FILE
```

I then turned it into a two dimensional list in python and it looks something like:

```
[['home', 'school', '5'], ['home','office','10'],['home','store','7'],
['school','store','8'], ['office','school','4']]
```

But the way that I would really like it is to be more in dictionary format such as:

```
{'home': {'school': 5, 'office': 10, 'store': 7},
'school': {'store': 8},
'office': {'school': 4}}
```

That format looks a lot better and is easier to read. The data that I have is lot more in detail but this is simple version. I have read my text file as follows:

```
myFileOpen = open(myInputFile, 'r')
myMap = myFileOpen.readlines()[:-1]

#Format the list, each line becomes a list in a greater list
myMap = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in myMap]
myMap = [i.split(' ') for i in myMap]
```

If anyone can help explain how to this I'd be very grateful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code may look like this:

```
result = {}
for item in data:
    result.setdefault(item[0], {}).update({item[1]: item[2]})
```

Proof with whole code: http://ideone.com/8XUA41

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you so much! If anyone looks at the link it does work with data hardcoded in, but the text file will be switched out so hardcoding is not an option. So I combined your answer with my already coded method of opening my file. Thank you for this method!

Answer (score 1):

Skip the intermediate list and just do it all at once:

```
d = {}

with open(myInputFile, 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        if line == 'END OF FILE':
            continue

        key1, key2, value = line.split()

        if key1 not in d:
            d[key1] = {}

        d[key1][key2] = int(value)
```

You could further condense that last part into:

```
d.setdefault(key1, {})[key2] = int(value)
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says SyntaxError: invalid syntax and it points to the with. I have looked this up and it says that the problem comes with people not being up to date with Python, but mine is.

Comment: @Ben: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: Well, upvote for suggesting simplification of the whole OP's code.

Comment: @Blender: I am currently running 3.3.2 but I am running my code on my school's server called OMEGA. But I have it working now without the 'with'. Your code was very helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

And the hack answer goes to:

```
txt =\
'''
home school 5
home office 10
home store 7
school store 8
office school 4
'''

txt = txt.strip()
gs = [line.split(" ") for line in txt.split("\n")]
ts = {}
[ts.setdefault(x, {}).setdefault(y, z) for (x, y, z) in gs]
print ts
```

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but it works with a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> L = [['home', 'school', '5'], ['home', 'office', '10'], ['home', 'store', '7'], ['school', 'store', '8'], ['office', 'school', '4']]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in L:
...     d[i[0]].append(i[1:])
...
>>> {k: dict(v) for k, v in d.items()} # Or d.iteritems with python 2.x
{'home': {'school': '5', 'store': '7', 'office': '10'}, 'school': {'store': '8'}, 'office': {'school': '4'}}
```

I'm not that experienced with using defaultdicts, so there's probably a better way.